# Ionic remove Header logo in sub page

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this Ionic App with a logo defined in the `view-title` like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="<img src='img/main-logo.png'>" ng-controller="ShoesCtrl as shoesItems">
...
</ion-view>
```

This results in this with a centered logo:

[image]

I then have items inside a page that go to a different template which is this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{single.name}}">
    <ion-content direction="y" scrollbar-y="false">
        {{single | json}}
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When I click an item this opens in the right page but instead of showing the usual "back" button the logo moves to the right, like this:

[image]

This happens only in the iOS version.
How do I remove the logo in the sub-page only and show a "Back" button.

The index is this:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: try this for custom nav button https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/

Comment: @AnujGupta great! It works! Place it as an answer so I can check it. Tks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look from https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"
    ng-click="myGoBack()">
    <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicHistory) {
  $scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };
}
```

It will work.